# user needs to input 10 elements in the array with JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

How does the program will ask 10 elements for the array with JOptionPane and then in the end it will show the 10 elements? It only ask one element and its done.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  

 public class Array1   
 {  
 public static void main(String[] args)   
 {  
 int n = 10;  
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  

 int[] array = new int[10];  

 JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter ten elements for the array: ");  

 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)  
 {  

 array[i]=sc.nextInt();  
 }  
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("The elements are: ");  

 for (int i=0; i<n; i++)   
 {  

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, array[i]);  
 }  
 }  
 }
```

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("The elements are: ");  ` is OUTSIDE of your loop.

Comment: Beyond that: you are mixing different concepts here. There is **no** sense in having A) a scanner of System.in (the command line / shell console) and B) a JOptionPane. You should either use the command line (textual input), or do all input using the JOptionPane (it has methods to RETURN you values entered to it).

Comment: Finally. in programming, details matter. As in: proper indenting of blocks. Alone the fact that you dont do ANY indenting makes your code 10 times harder to read than necessary. Be diligent about your work. And stick with ONE concept. Pick up a book, read carefully and follow the examples given there. Dont try to event your own things at this point.